# Why can I only boot into Ubuntu 18.04 via recovery mode?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, recovery-mode

I dual boot with Win 10 & Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. However can only boot into Ubuntu via recovery mode. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks too all for their assistance so far  :)

Comment: Can you provide more details in your question? "Where did I go wrong" would be significantly easier to solve if you could state some relevant events that happened before you noticed the issue.

Comment: Alas kind sir but am cluelesss about what I might have done to cause the problem. Installed the distro & then restarted as it wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you and I had the same problem. For me it was fixed by following this question ([Nvidia driver 410 listed by ppa and ubuntu-drivers but does not seem to be installable via apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085605/nvidia-driver-410-listed-by-ppa-and-ubuntu-drivers-but-does-not-seem-to-be-insta)) and installing the appropriate Nividia drivers. Go to **Software & Updates** on your computer, open the **Additional Drivers** window. Take note of the Nvidia product number (mine is GeForce 840M version 410.78). Then go to https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx enter your product info into the drop menus the press Search. Download the package.

Next clear out your old drivers in terminal with,

```
apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
```

use `cd` to navigate to your `Downloads` folder and enter the following (with your product numbers) into terminal.

```
sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.66.run  `
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.66.run 
sudo reboot`
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my NVIDIA driver at Software & Updates, Additional Drivers section, from "xserver-xorg" to "nvidia-driver-510" did the trick.
I'm using an Acer Nitro 5 with a GTX 1650.

Comment: What worked for you? Actually I've started with onb's solution  What does this mean? Your answer as written makes no sense.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I didn't mean to post a new solution, just add to the other comment. Is it better now ?