# Nvidia driver 410 listed by ppa and ubuntu-drivers but does not seem to be installable via apt

Tags: drivers, apt, 18.04, nvidia, ppa

I have a GTX 660M and Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit.

According to [the official website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx), the latest graphics driver for this card is version 410.66.

The [graphics-drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) says

```
Current long-lived branch release: `nvidia-410` (410.66)
```

I have nouveau drivers installed at the moment according to `lsmod` and, `apt-get purge 'nvidia*'` does nothing.

I have done `add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers` and `apt-get update` and a reboot.

Running `ubuntu-drivers devices` gives this output

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000FD4sv00001028sd00000551bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GK107M [GeForce GTX 660M]
driver   : nvidia-304 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Note this line:

```
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free recommended
```

It looks like everything is ready to go to install driver version 410, but autocompleting `apt-get install nvidia-` indicates the highest available version is `nvidia-390`, and trying `apt-get install nvidia-410` directly fails.

Why does `apt` not list the version 410 that the PPA and `ubuntu-drivers` both say is there?

And if I can't `apt-get install nvidia-410`, how can I install this version?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before trying to manually install the proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver version 410.6 I recommend that you try to install it again from the terminal with these commands instead.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410 # nvidia-driver-410 has been updated to nvidia-driver-430 in 18.04
sudo reboot
```

Please note that the correct name of the package that you need to install is *nvidia-driver-410* (NVIDIA driver metapackage) not *nvidia-410*. Installing the NVIDIA driver metapackage will install the NVIDIA graphics driver and several of its required dependency packages.

**Update**: The nvidia-driver-410 package in the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories has been upgraded to nvidia-driver-430.

---

If `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410 && sudo reboot` doesn't work, you can also download the NVIDIA 410.6 graphics driver from the official NVIDIA website and install it manually.

1. The official [NVIDIA DRIVERS Linux x64](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/138959/en-us) webpage -> *Supported products* tab shows that the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660M GPU is compatible with the Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver version 410.6. Click the green **Download** button on the NVIDIA DRIVERS Linux x64 webpage to download this driver (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.66.run).
2. Open the terminal and change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.66.run file that you downloaded.
3. Install NVIDIA Linux x64  Display Driver version 410.6.

   ```
    sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.66.run  
    sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.66.run  
    sudo reboot
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install by selecting the specific packages, like this:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-410 libnvidia-gl-410 nvidia-utils-410 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410 libnvidia-cfg1-410 libnvidia-ifr1-410 libnvidia-decode-410 libnvidia-encode-410
```

Just like @karel said. I wanted to share the dependencies.

Comment: Packages which you added are automatically installed when installing nvidia-driver-xxx so no need to add them manually